# Deploy ecommerce website

Tags: asp.net

How I can deploy my Asp.NET web application without affect the current application? My application is an e-commerce web site and I need it to be the shortest possible time offline.

Thanks.

Comment: This is more of a ServerFault question...

Answer (score 1):

Set it up on the production box with dev headers (ie dev.website.com) in IIS and then when you've tested and ensured it will work, change the headers to be www.website.com and website.com